# Get a "HTMLInputElement" type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typeerror

There is a `<input type="checkbox" id="mainCheckbox" />`,I want to use the property `checked` of it.And the vscode waring `Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'`.I know that must be type `HTMLInputElement`,But I can't change it,the method `getElementById()` is return the type `HTMLElement`;

```js
var controlCheckbox= document.getElementById("mainCheckbox"),
    addBtn = document.getElementById("btn_add"),
    container = document.getElementById("observers");
ObserverSubject.extend(new ObserverSubject.Subject(), controlCheckbox);
controlCheckbox.onclick=()=>{
    this.Notify(controlCheckbox.checked);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Not working,warning 
`Type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement'.
  Property 'accept' is missing in type 'HTMLElement'`,
if I rewrite the code
`var controlCheckbox:HTMLInputElement = document.getElementById("mainCheckbox")`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Updated to 2023 `typescript`:

```
const controlCheckbox = document.getElementById("mainCheckbox") as HTMLInputElement;
```

ֿֿTry this simple cast:

```
var controlCheckbox = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("mainCheckbox")
```

Comment: do you have to import anything to use <HTMLInputElement>?

Comment: @SaurabhRana no you do not